# socket error when connecting paho.mqtt.python to mosquitto broker

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm trying to connect from python script(paho.mqtt.python) to mosquitto broker.
I can connect from terminal using this command:

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 8883 -v -t 'owntracks/#' -u owntracks -P 12qwaszx
```

But when I'm trying to connect via python script I'm getting the error:

```
Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

The script I'm using is the example:
(from here: https://owntracks.org/booklet/tech/program/)

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json

# The callback for when the client successfully connects to the broker
def on_connect(client, userdata, rc):
    ''' We subscribe on_connect() so that if we lose the connection
        and reconnect, subscriptions will be renewed. '''

    client.subscribe("owntracks/+/+")
    #tried also: client.subscribe("owntracks/#")
# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the broker
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):

    topic = msg.topic

    try:
        data = json.loads(str(msg.payload))

        print "TID = {0} is currently at {1}, {2}".format(data['tid'], data['lat'], data['lon'])
    except:
        print "Cannot decode data on topic {0}".format(topic)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("localhost", 8883, 60)

# Blocking call which processes all network traffic and dispatches
# callbacks (see on_*() above). It also handles reconnecting.

client.loop_forever()
```

Here is the content of my config file (I changed the "localhost" from my real IP - tried both of them):

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
listener 8883 "localhost"
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
persistence_file mosquitto.db
log_dest syslog
log_dest stdout
log_dest topic
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of mosquitto are you using and how is it configured (specifically is port 8883 set up for websockets?)

Comment: version 1.5.8. it's configured using this configuration: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-setup-a-mosquitto-mqtt-server-and-receive-data-from-owntracks

Comment: Rather than localhost or your IP address try removing it (by default mosquitto will then listen on all available IP/interfaces)

Comment: Changed, and I also removed the password, so I can connect from terminal without specifying IP and password, but still have the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Your python script is attempting to connect to what looks like a TLS secured setup without preparing the client connect method to apply these details to the transaction. Try the following:

```
def ssl_prep():
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
        ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cafile=ca)
        ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=mycert, keyfile=priv)
        return  ssl_context

ca = "PATH_TO_YOUR_CA_FILE"
priv = "PATH_TO_YOUR_PEM_FILE"
mycert = "PATH_TO_YOUR_CERT_FILE"
topics = "YOUR_TOPICS"
broker = "BROKER_URL"
client = mqtt.Client()
ssl_context= ssl_prep()

client.tls_set_context(context=ssl_context)
client.username_pw_set(username="UNAME",password="PASS")
client.connect(broker, port=8883)
```

By providing the ssl context to the connection attempt before the attempt is made, this should connect assuming you have all the detail specific to your own setup in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the KeepAlive time from 1min to 30sec or lower:

```
client.connect("localhost", 8883, 30)
//Default: connect(host, port=1883, keepalive=60, bind_address=””)
```